# Link using Java not working when two version of java installed

Tags: java, windows

I have a link say ( `http://server2193:4050` ) and this link works on java version 6 and I have so many applications that work on Java 7 so I have both versions available.

Problem I am facing is that above mentioned link stopped working when I installed Java 7 and if I uninstall Java 7, link works fine.

How can I solve this problem?
I am using Windows 7 and I need both Java version together.

Comment: I think your problem might be related to  path variable environment

Comment: I have this in path variable : %JAVA_HOME%\bin and JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29